# Can I have the same route handler for two routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have these two routes defined:

```
<Route name='register' handler={Register} >
    <Route name='registerpromotion' path='/registerpromotion/:promotionCode' handler={Register}/>
</Route>
```

So both routes use the same handler called Register.

In the case of the **registerpromotion** route, I pass in a property and in the case of the **register** route, I do not.

I could not get this to work - the promotionCode property is always undefined.

Does anyone know if you can use the same handler for two routes?

Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to have the `Route`s nested like this?  The way you have it, `Register` will have a child `Register`, but the inner component will never have another child.  Seems like a strange setup that could be part of the problem.

Comment: Answered here:https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/410

Answer (score 0):

This code is from [react-router issue #410](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/410#issuecomment-59231369) by rpflorence:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');
var Router = require('react-router');
var Route = Router.Route;
var Routes = Router.Routes;
var Link = Router.Link;

var Foo = React.createClass({  
  render: function() { 
    return (
      <div>
        <p>hello</p>
        <p>stuffId: {this.props.params.stuffId}</p>
        <ul>
          <li><Link to="root">top</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="stuff" params={{stuffId: 'one'}}>one</Link></li>
          <li><Link to="stuff" params={{stuffId: 'two'}}>two</Link></li>
        </ul>
        <this.props.activeRouteHandler />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var routes = (
  <Routes>
    <Route name="root" path="/" handler={Foo}>
      <Route name="stuff" path=":stuffId" handler={Foo}/>
    </Route>
  </Routes>
);

React.renderComponent(routes, document.body);
```